# How to make a stable sort of binary values in linear time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

Let us suppose that we have a:

```
class Widget;
std::vector<Widget>;
```

And we have a function:

```
bool belongsToLeft(Widget w);
```

I would like to sort the container according to this predicate. So far I though up this algorithm. It progresses from both ends of the range. Once it finds a pair of values that simultaneously belong to the other end, it swaps them.

```
template <typename TIterator, typename TPredicate>
TIterator separate(TIterator begin, TIterator end, TPredicate belongsLeft)
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (begin != end && belongsLeft(*begin))
            ++begin;
        while (begin != end && !belongsLeft(*end))
            --end;
        if (begin == end)
            return begin;
        std::swap(*begin, *end);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this algorithm is not stable:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    separate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](int x){return x%2 == 0;});

    for (int x : numbers)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
6
2
4
3
5
1
```

How can I modify this algorithm to be stable and keep the linear time?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::stable_sort()`?

Comment: I want to make use of the fact that there are only two possible values so that the algorithm runs in linear time.

Comment: The swap should only be made when `*end > *begin` which is not guaranteed; place the predicate on begin/end.

Comment: What exactly do you think is wrong with the output in your example?

Comment: @Steven I want a stable sort. That is the numbers should appear in the same relative order as in the input: 6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1

Comment: @Joop it is guaranteed. In order to get to the swap both belongsLeft(*begin) and !belongsLeft(*end) need to fail

Comment: @MartinDrozdik I erred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::stable_partition` with a predicate to seperate `numbers` into two parts in linear complexity

```
#include <algorithm>

std::stable_partition(
    numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 
    [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; } // or belongsToLeft()
);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! The standard library never ceases to amaze me!

Comment: If you know what your hand-written algorithm needs to do, think of an appropriate name, and then use a thesaurus to find alternative names that resemble Standard Library algorithms E.g. http://thesaurus.com/browse/separate and it shows partitioned as an entry